# validating failover cluster stuck on " List software update"

Tags: cluster-computing, windows-server-2012-r2, failover

I created a cluster before and weirdly the cluster had a slight problem. I was forced to destroy it.

However I deleted his IP address from the AD and rebuilt the cluster, but when I validate my cluster It stucks on "List Software Updates". would someone have a solution? Is it because of the cached files of the old cluster? How should i fix it ? thank you

configuration: I have two VM on windows server 2012 R2
I used the AlwaysOnFailover cluster service as a service on the old cluster.

[i got this !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs3bM.jpg)

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I have a 2 subnet cluster which refuses to let me build an AG listener. "validate cluster" always sticks at software updates. windows/sql 2019.